# Telescope: Adding categories, messed up slug?

Tags: telescope

Is anyone else having this issue? When I tried to add a category, the URL to the category isn't correct.

It adds a "category/{slug name}"

example: .comcategory/style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add "/" to the end of "Site URL"

"http://www.yourdomain.com/"